Node Exporter: couldn't get dbus connection
I use helm chart node_exporter. In this values.yaml https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus-node-exporter/values.yaml I only changed these lines
hostRootFsMount:
  enabled: true
 
nodeSelector:
  kubernetes.io/os: linux
 
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: WSL
          operator: DoesNotExist

extraArgs:
  - --collector.systemd

securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: false
  runAsUser: 0

Now I'm getting an error:
ts=2024-07-01T08:12:22.326Z caller=collector.go:169 level=error msg="collector failed" name=systemd duration_seconds=0.007097623 err="couldn't get dbus connection: dial unix /run/systemd/private: connect: no such file or directory"
ts=2024-07-01T08:12:23.081Z caller=collector.go:169 level=error msg="collector failed" name=systemd duration_seconds=5.375e-05 err="couldn't get dbus connection: dial unix /run/systemd/private: connect: no such file or directory"
ts=2024-07-01T08:12:37.323Z caller=collector.go:169 level=error msg="collector failed" name=systemd duration_seconds=6.3801e-05 err="couldn't get dbus connection: dial unix /run/systemd/private: connect: no such file or directory"
ts=2024-07-01T08:12:48.081Z caller=collector.go:169 level=error msg="collector failed" name=systemd duration_seconds=4.1157e-05 err="couldn't get dbus connection: dial unix /run/systemd/private: connect: no such file or directory"

